# Having issue with magento 1.9 with API handling

Tags: magento-1.9, product, api, google-api

I had worked as below the steps, once after the completing the processing.
I am getting 404 error with my api request.

refer : https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/rest/authentication/oauth_authentication.html

step 1 : /oauth/initiate  (will get OauthToken & OauthTokenSecret)

step 2 :/bkadmin/oauth_authorize?oauth_token  (call back)

step 3 :/oauth/token (will get AccessToken & AccessTokenSecret)

upto this, working

after this using AccessToken & AccessTokenSecret can't get products

http://famara.in/shop/index.php/api/rest/products